# Swift--Fatal Error when passing CoreData between controllers

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here I have two table view controllers, named: `customerTableViewController` and `customOrderListTableViewController`. I try to pass CoreData from `customerTableViewController` to  `customOrderListTableViewController` when click cell in `customerTableViewController`. I had made a segue "showCustomerOrderList" through storyBoard.

But the data in destination controller always print

> "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

when I use retaliated entity-attributes which passed in. How could I fix this? 
Here is the code:

```
//in customerTableViewController:
import CoreData
var customer: [Customer] = []    
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCustomerOrderList" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! customOrderListTableViewController
        controller.customer = customer[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }
//in customOrderListTableViewController:
import CoreData
     var customer: Customer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("\(self.customer.customerName)")  //error here: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}
```

Comment: correct the name of destination view controller in prepare method. Write "customerOrderListTableViewController" instead of "customOrderListTableViewController"

Comment: sorry for this miss type in Question writing. Its: customOrderListTableViewController

Comment: Check if `prepare(for segue:sender:)` is called, and check if it's after `func viewDidLoad()`. If it's after, you connected the Segue from the `UITableViewCell` to the `customOrderListTableViewController`. Instead, remove it, connect it from `customerTableViewController` to `customOrderListTableViewController`, and implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath and do performSegue there.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Tracking by following your comments, It works now!